# Autocorrelation function and power spectral density

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, correlation

I want to get the autocorrelation function of the power spectral density of the wind.

This function is defined by:
$$s(\omega)=\frac{c_1}{(1+1.5 \times c_2\omega)^{5/3}}$$
$c_1$ and $c_2$ are constants. Any help please.

I specify that the autocorrelation function is done by the integral of :
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \! s(\omega) \times \exp(I \times \tau \times \omega) \, \mathrm{d}\omega$$

with $-\infty < \tau <+\infty $ and $I^2=−1$

Comment: By * do you mean the convolution operator or just the multiplication?

Comment: the symbol * means multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

Assumig that $*$ means usual multiplication and $c_2>0$,
the following plan should work:

1.) Rescale $c_2\omega =\tilde\omega$

2.) Substitute  $\tilde\omega = q-1$

3.) Integrate by parts, choosing $f'(q)=q^{-5/3}, g(q)=e^{i  q \tilde{\tau} }$  with $\tilde{\tau}=\tau/c_2$ to lower the degree of the singulartiy at $0$.

4.) Use formula 318 from this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) . It can be proven by contour integration methods, using a half circle contour in the (upper/lower) halfplane excluding the branch cut on the positive/negative imaginary axis

Can you get it from here?

Comment: I have done the calculus and this is what I got: $$I = \frac{3\pi c_1}{c_2}(-1)^{\frac{^5}{6}}u(\frac{\tau}{c_2})\times \frac{\left(\frac{\tau}{c_2} \right)^\frac{2}{3}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{3} \right)\times exp\left(\frac{i*\tau}{c_2} \right)}$$. u is the Heaviside function.

Comment: @ Mhenni Benghorbal  any help  or ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have done this development:
assume that : $\omega=\frac{q-1}{c2}$, so the integral becomes:
$$I_1 = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\! q^\left( -\frac{5}{3}\right)\times exp\left(i\omega\tau\right) \, \mathrm{d}\omega = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\! q^\left( -\frac{5}{3}\right)\times exp\left(i\tau\frac{q-1}{c2}\right) \, \mathrm{d}\omega.$$
$$=\frac{1}{c2}\times \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\! q^\left( -\frac{5}{3}\right)\times exp\left(i\tau\frac{q-1}{c2}\right) \, \mathrm{d}q$$
After substitution of $\bar{\tau}=\frac{\tau}{c2}$, we find:
$$I_1 = \frac{1}{c2\times exp(i\bar{\tau})} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \! q^{-\frac{5}{3}}\times exp\left(iq\bar{\tau}\right) \, \mathrm{d}q$$
Can you help me for the rest.